# In JavaScript how can I use a function parameter as the key to an object?

Tags: javascript

For example the following code prints

> { key: 'b' }

```
function myFunc(key, value) {
    myFunc2({key: value});
}

function myFunc2(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}

myFunc('a', 'b');
```

How would I get it to print

> { 'a': 'b' }

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add properties separately from construction:

```
function myFunc(key, value) { 
  var item = {};
  item[key] = value;
  myFunc2(item);
}
```

Comment: JsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kjAPH/, note that getting `a` quoted will likely require custom print mehtod instead of default FF log call. Note 2 - IE will not output what you want - "LOG: [object Object]" instead.

Answer (score 23):

ES6

```
function myFunc(key, value) {
  myFunc2({[`${key}`]: value});
}
```

[Enhanced Object Literals](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, keys in Javascript object literals ({}) must be literal, not a variable. Use the conventional Object syntax.

```
function myFunc(key, value) {
    myObj = new Object();
    myObj[key] = value;
    myFunc2(myObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a=new Object();
a[key]=value;
myFunc2(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunc(key, value) {
    var obj = new Object();
    obj[key] = value;
    console.log(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in short:

```
function myFunc(key, value) {
    var tmp = {};
    myFunc2((tmp[key] = value,tmp));
}
```